# How i can make ProgressBar corner straight not rounded?

Tags: android, rounded-corners

I have created the following progressbar style and set the corner radius to both shapes (background, and pogress). But how i make corner straight not rounded?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTpox.png)

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://www.zoftino.com/android-progressbar-and-custom-progressbar-examples for customization in ProgressBar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would love to help you, but there are some problems in the current format/content of your question that makes it hard for some of us to help. If you haven't done so already, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so it will be easier for us to help you.